# general tbb issue for calculating fibonacci numbers

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, tbb

I came across the tbb template below as an example of task-based programming for calculating the sum of fibonacci numbers in c++. But when I run it I get a value of 1717986912 which can't be the case. The output should be 3. What am I doing wrong?

```
  class FibTask: public task 
  {
public:
const long n;
long * const sum;
FibTask( long n_, long* sum_ ) : n(n_), sum(sum_) {}

    task* execute( )
    { 
        // Overrides virtual function task::execute
    if( n < 0) 
    {
        return 0;
    } 
    else 
    {
        long x, y;
        FibTask& a = *new( allocate_child( ) ) FibTask(n-1,&x);
        FibTask& b = *new( allocate_child( ) ) FibTask(n-2,&y);
        // Set ref_count to "two children plus one for the wait".
        set_ref_count(3);
        // Start b running.
        spawn( b );
        // Start a running and wait for all children (a and b).
        spawn_and_wait_for_all( a );
        // Do the sum
        *sum = x+y;
    }
        return NULL;
}

long ParallelFib( long n ) 
{
    long sum;
    FibTask& a = *new(task::allocate_root( )) FibTask(n,&sum);
    task::spawn_root_and_wait(a);
    return sum;
}
  };



    long main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FibTask * obj = new FibTask(3,0);
    long b = obj->ParallelFib(3);
    std::cout << b;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Seems it has something to do with uninitialized `x` and `y`?

Comment: `long main` is non-standard.

Comment: @Cheers, yea, also the `execute()` return values are all messed up with those `0` and `NULL`, but I think it's irrelevant)

Comment: I have tried it. It didn't help. I have literally copied and pasted the code from http://www.cs.rice.edu/~johnmc/comp522/lecture-notes/COMP522-2013-Lecture9-TBB.pdf but when I call it it does't work.

Comment: @user3017335 Maybe because different compiler intializes, `x` and `y` to some value by default. But this is non-standard. If I recall correctly, in c++ only class members and global variables are guaranteed to be initialized by default.

Comment: @luk32; class members are not guaranteed initialization. that depends (mostly) on the constructors of the class, if any. for a class sans constructors it depends on the object creation.

Comment: I'm sorry, the answer I wrote was completely wrong. Deleted. But I think earlier comment probably relevant.

Comment: I have tried everything but it still does not output the correct result. Any other ideas?

Comment: Part of the definition of Fibonacci is that F(1) = 1 and F(2) = 1.  I see no were in your FibTask that it returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

The cutoff is messed here. It must be 2 at least. E.g.:

```
if( n<2 ) {
    *sum = n;
    return NULL;
}
```

The original example also uses SerialFib as showed here http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/Simple_Example_Fibonacci_Numbers.htm

The inefficient method for calculating Fibonacci numbers using inefficient blocking style technique will be even more inefficient without call to SerialFib().

WARNING: Please note that this example is intended just to demonstrate this particular low-level TBB API and this particular way of using it. It is not intended for reuse unless you are really sure why you are doing this.

Modern high-level API (though, still for the inefficient Fibonacci algorithm) would look like this:

```
int Fib(int n) {
    if( n<CUTOFF ) { // 2 is minimum
        return fibSerial(n);
    } else {
        int x, y;
        tbb::parallel_invoke([&]{x=Fib(n-1);}, [&]{y=Fib(n-2);});
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I don't quite understand. Should long SerialFib and long ParallelFib be defined within the scope of class FibTask??

Comment: "WARNING: Please note that this example is intended just to demonstrate this particular low-level TBB API and this particular way of using it. It is not intended for reuse unless you are really sure why you are doing this." Then what should I amend to this code to run it??

Comment: This won't work. you are supposed to return `*task` not `long`. This really does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @luk32, thanks. I meant 'return' the sum directly, without recursion. I'll fix

Comment: Yea, now it works, one could also write `long x = 0, y = 1;` and it would also produce correct series, shifted by 1. But it would be even uglier solution. You posted too little code with out context, and mentioned `SerialFib` which is not really needed. Now it is clearer and works if you use your `if`. I find this whole example ugly as hell. GJ on making it work =)

Comment: updated to include high-level example. If you curious which algorithm will allow you to compute Fib efficiently in parallel, please ask another question :)
thanks, @luk32!